# How to create a recurring task in ClickUp via API?

Tags: clickup-api

ClickUp allows us to create recurring tasks (as I show in the attached screenshot), for example, that figure due date every week on Tuesday.

I would like to know if we can create a recurring task in ClickUp through API. And if possible how is it done? what is the endpoint and what parameters are needed.

Checking their documentation, I didn't find any references to recurring tasks: https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/CreateTask/

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I see two options: either to set recurring times manually during the task creation ( https://app.clickup.com/2537297/v/dc/2dduh-1492/2dduh-9781 ) or give a shot to task templates, but I'm not sure template would handle the recurrency properly ( https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/CreateTaskFromTemplate/ )